# How to write mysql query correctly?

Tags: c++, mysql

I have that error: "
C++ error expression must have integral or enum type "

Whats incorrect?

```
std::string login, password;

query_state = mysql_query(connection, "SELECT id FROM users WHERE login=" + "'" + login1 + "'" + " AND password=" + "'" + password1 + "'");
```

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us, and then copy-paste the *full* and *complete* output when building that example. Also please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I don't even know if C++ supports string concatenation like that (your code looks more like Java to me), but in any case you should be using a prepared statement.  Another aside: it appears that you are storing cleartext passwords in your `users` table.  This is bad practice, because if someone ever gets unauthorized access to that table, they can easily get credentials for every user in your system.

Comment: `mysql_query()` is a C library function that knows absolutely nothing about C++'s `std::string` or any other C++ class. Your C++ book should have plenty of examples of taking a `std::string` and getting a C-style plain string out of it that `mysql_query()` would understand. But before you proceed, you need to learn all about things like "SQL injection" and "hacking", that the above query likely makes possible...

Comment: On another note, your code is flawed in that it allows SQL-injection. Read the tale of little [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/). To fix it read about [prepared statements and binding variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/c-api-prepared-statement-data-structures.html).

Comment: Lastly, and since you're programming in C++, perhaps you should use [the C++ connector](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/connector-cpp-info.html) instead of the plain C API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with mysql. You should read the comments and fix the problems regarding the database connection.

The error message means that old cstrings can't be concatenated like this. You can either use [strcat](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat) (bad)

```
char query[200];
strcpy(query, "SELECT id FROM users WHERE login='");
strcat(query, login1);
strcat(query, "' AND password='");
strcat(query, password1);
strcat(query, "'");
query_state = mysql_query(connection, query);
```

or [std::string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) (good).

```
std::string query = std::string("SELECT id FROM users WHERE login='") + std::string(login1) + std::string("' AND password='") + std::string(password1) + std::string("'");
query_state = mysql_query(connection, query.c_str());
```

You should avoid the use of old cstrings.